# Programmatically set class on extended field type

Tags: 8, entities

Earlier I created an extended version of the Node class. I called it AbleNode and it extended BaseNode. In order to set all nodes to this node type I added this to my custom .module file

```
function ablecore_entity_type_build(&$entity_types){
    if(isset($entity_types['node'])){
        $entity_types['node']->setClass('Drupal\ablecore\Plugin\Node\AbleNode');
    }
}
```

This works fine but I'm not sure how to do this with an extended field type. Here is the code for my field class that is extending the BaseFileFieldItemList class

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\ablecore\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList;
/**
 * @file AbleNode.php
 */
use Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList as BaseFileFieldItemList;

class AbleFileFieldItemList extends BaseFileFieldItemList {
    public function style($image_style) {
        $image_style = \Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle::load($image_style);
        if (!empty($image_style)) {
            return $image_style->buildUrl($this->getEntity()->getFileuri());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I see how I was able to turn all nodes into AbleNodes, but I'm not sure how to make all FileFieldItemLists into AbleFileFieldItemLists. Is there a hook I can use to setClass on the field whenever I encounter it? Keep in mind that I'm not trying to create a brand new field, I just want to give more functionality to existing field types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested, but I'm pretty sure you just need to change the list class for the field types using [`hook_field_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_info_alter/8.5.x):

```
function ablecore_field_info_alter(&$info) {
  foreach ($info as &$field) {
    if ($field['list_class'] == '\Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList') {
      $field['list_class'] = '\Drupal\ablecore\Plugin\Field\FieldType\AbleFileFieldItemList';
    }
  }
}
```